# How to create a dict from list where values are elements of the list and keys are function of those elements in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of `caller_address` elements. For each of these addresses I can get a `caller_function`, a function containing that `caller_address`. In a single function there may be more than 1 address.
So if I have a list of `caller_address` elements:

```
caller_addresses = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

For each of them I can get a function:

```
caller_functions = [getFunctionContaining(addr) for addr in caller_addresses]
print(caller_functions)
# prints(example): ['func1', 'func1', 'func2', 'func2', 'func2', 'func2', 'func3', 'func3']
```

In the result I need to get a dict where keys are the functions and values are lists of addresses those functions contain. In my example in must be:

```
{'func1': [1, 2], 'func2': [3, 4, 5, 6], 'func3': [7, 8]}
# Means 'func1' contains addresses 1 and 2, 'func2' contains 3, 4, 5 and 6, ...
```

It would be great if there was a function like:

```
result = to_dict(lambda addr: getFunctionContaining(addr), caller_addresses)
```

to get the same result.
Where the first argument is the function for keys and the second argument is the list of values. Is there such function in standard library in python?

I could implement it with for loop and `dict[getFunctionContaining(addr)].append(addr)`, but I'm looking for more pythonic way to do this.
Thanks!

Comment: The loop is probably by far the simplest solution… Loops aren't unpythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution using `itertools.groupby`.
This solution is also faster than a solution using a loop.

```
import itertools
import time

def f(v):
    if v < 5:
        return 1
    if v < 7:
        return 2
    return 3

def to_dict(key, list_):
    out = {}

    for el in list_:
        out.setdefault(key(el), []).append(el)

    return out

def to_dict2(key, list_):
    return {k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(list_, key)}

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] * 10**4

COUNT = 1000

def timeit(to_dict_f):
    elapsed_sum = 0
    for _ in range(COUNT):
        elapsed_sum -= time.time()
        to_dict_f(f, lst)
        elapsed_sum += time.time()
    return elapsed_sum / COUNT

print('Average time: ', timeit(to_dict), timeit(to_dict2))
```

Results:

```
Average time:  0.014930561065673828 0.01346096110343933
```

`to_dict2` (`itertools.groupby`) on average takes less time than `to_dict` (loop)